# How to get value of all row and set in array in libre calc with marco

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

If i want to get value all of row in table and I want to set it in array . How I shound do ?

Please advice me  , Thanks a lot .

```
Sub Cut 'This method is cut value from user selectio and set to Copy variable.
Selection = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are asking about. But if the goal is to get the DataArray from selected cells, then the following should do that:

```
Sub getArrayFromSelection

 oSelection = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()

 if oSelection.supportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRange") then
  aDataArray = oSelection.getDataArray()
  lRows = ubound(aDataArray)
  lCols = ubound(aDataArray(0))
  for lRow = 0 to lRows
   for lCol = 0 to lCols
    msgbox aDataArray(lRow)(lCol)
   next
  next
 end if

End Sub
```